# symlink - race condition Kernel hardening [Apache]

Tags: apache, kernel, symlink, race-condition, whm

Issue : installation of kernel for symlink race issue.

I am writing for a solution to the below problem. I have looked around this site and others but have not found an answer that matches my understanding of the issue with a good explanation of how to fix it ( from a novice point of view).

I am slowly working my way around managing my server, I cant afford for anyone else to do it as it is too expensive. When I look at a lot of the answers they jump straight in to highbrow terminology and fixes that I cant seem to replicate.

My server is running CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 standard  WHM 62.0 (build 15).

The issue is below.

> Kernel does not support the prevention of symlink ownership attacks.
>   You do not appear to have any symlink protection enabled through a properly patched kernel on this server, which provides additional protections beyond those solutions employed in userland. Please review the documentation to learn how to apply this protection.
>
> I have followed the steps to harden the Kernel as per here
>   [Cpanel Documentation on hardening Kernel](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/Symlink+Race+Condition+Protection)

I am using SSH Cryptonaut to access command line.

I go to the degisnated folder, then download the Kernel then go to update..

The issue is it will not update, the return is :No Packages marked for Update.

> Last login: Tue Feb 28 21:29:28 2017 from xx.xx.xx.xx
>   [xxxxx@xxxxxxx ~]# cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
>   [xxxx@xxxxxxx yum.repos.d]# yum -y update kernel
>   Loaded plugins: tsflags, universal-hooks
>   Setting up Update Process
>   No Packages marked for Update
>   [xxxx@xxxxxxxx yum.repos.d]# wget https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/cPkernel/cPkernel.repo
>   --2017-02-28 21:57:39--  https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/cPkernel/cPkernel.repo
>   Resolving securedownloads.cpanel.net... 208.74.123.12, 208.74.121.38
>   Connecting to securedownloads.cpanel.net|208.74.123.12|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>   Length: 208
>   Saving to: “cPkernel.repo.4”

100%[========================================================================>] 208         --.-K/s   in 0s

2017-02-28 21:57:43 (23.2 MB/s) - “cPkernel.repo.4” saved [208/208]

[xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx yum.repos.d]# yum -y update kernel
Loaded plugins: tsflags, universal-hooks
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
[xxxxx@xxxxxx yum.repos.d]# 
>

**Is anyone able to help on this issue and include a simple steps on how to resolve.**

I am doing this for Symlink Race condition protection. I understand the symlink issue, but not so sure what the race condition means.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if you have in WHM Easyapache 3 or Easyapache 4. Btw for EA 3 is already announced EOL(end of life) so you must upgrade to EA4 in the near future if you have EA 3.

I use Easyapache 4 with default cPanel package(prefork + PHP-FPM) which have mod_ruid2 package as default at install(Remember that mod_ruid2 is not declared anymore "Experimental" by cPanel).

**So I choose the easy solution to solve symlink attacks on Centos:**

WHM > Tweak Settings > (at Find type: ruid) > enable: Jail Apache Virtual Hosts using mod_ruid2 and cPanel® jailshell.
Is declared as EXPERIMENTAL this method because sometimes can conflict with Mailman(if you don't use Mailman is everything OK).

**- Restart Apache**

WHM > Security Advisor > Scan again and check if your server have patched Symlink Race condition.

I use this method for months without a problem!